# algorithms in natural language processing

Tags: java, algorithm, logic, nlp

Im doing a project which could detect users emotions by text. Im using my own algorithm to do this from java.Im not sure whether this algorithm is good or bad.What are the weaknesses in this algorithm?

Here is what im doing.

1) Add pos tagging to the text.

2)get the sentiment of the text.

3) Extract the adjectives from the sentence and check in the database for each adjective. If it found a word add points to the found emotion.
at last get the emotion with the highest points.